# How do I manually import .h files into the system library?

Tags: mysql, c, macos, static-libraries, include-path

I have some C code that `#include`s the file `<mysql/mysql.h>`.  I am running on a Mac, and cannot figure out how to get `mysql` installed (after running the solution found on SO, the `mysql` directory does not even exist in the system library).  I was able to download MySQL from the source code, and now I have a `mysql.h` file-- in the "include" directory of the source code.

However, moving this file into the system library alone will obviously not make my program work.  I expect that I need to compile the library (which I've done), and to move the binary file somewhere, in order to be linkable to my program.

As per @RustyX's suggestion, I installed the Mac MySQL package.  That put a copy of `mysql.h` into the `/usr/local/mysql-5.7.19-macos10.12-x86_64/include/` directory.  However:

1) I am using `gcc` to compile the .c file.  I am not sure how to configure `gcc` to include the directory in question.  I tried 
`-L(directory path)`-- both for the installed Mac MySQL package, and the MySQL source code I downloaded-- but I get the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lmysqlclient
```

Is there another path I would include for `mysqlclient`?  Or another package to install?

2) Even if I do include it, it will still not find the file since the called-for filename is `<mysql/mysql.h>`, and the filename it will find is `<include/mysql.h>`.  Since the file is used by others, is the best course of action here to rename the `include` directory to `mysql`?  Or to change the path in the .c file, and then change it back every time before committing?

Comment: Ehh.. 1) Install the [mysql package](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/osx-installation-pkg.html), 2) Configure additional include and lib paths for your project (something like /usr/local/mysql...)

Comment: Tried your solution, and got stuck; see the post above for updated status.

Comment: I think you're confusing includes and libraries. If you've done `make install` it would print the directories and files that were created/installed. You need to set the right -I argument and -L argument based on how the install went. Also, you say you tried -L with dir. In that directory, did you find `libmysqlclient.dylib` installed?

Comment: @UnmannedPlayer I have the installation log still in the terminal-- but I'm not sure how to deduce the correct directory `based on how the install went`.  However, when I did `-L(path to libmysqlclient.dylib)`, and then the program compiled successfully.  Totally unexpected, since the directory containing that file is actually hidden.  For future reference (in case I have to do this with another package)-- how did you know that this was the file that `-L` needed to point to a directory with?  Feel free to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a statement like this,

```
#include <mysql.h> //in your program
```

To compile and run

```
gcc -w -c -g -I/usr/include/mysql filename.c
gcc -o filename filename.o -L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient
./filename (input params)
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this, and when it said `fatal error: 'mysql.h' file not found`, then I tried instead #including the full path of `mysql.h`.  At that point, it gave the errors I quoted in my post.  But for the `-L` argument, I put `-L/Users/pc/Downloads/mysql-5.0.92/include`-- which is the directory that has the `mysql.h` file.  Maybe I should use a different one?